# Springboot authentication issue with customer login

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I have a spring boot application with spring security configured. I have redirected the login request to `http://localhost:8000` where I'm running my front-end on a python server. Now when I try to post the login to my springboot application, it doesn't work. I looked into some posts online and changed the login path to /j_spring_security_check but it doesn't even seem to be trying to login as I don't see any logs in the console.  Its taking me to login?error .Are there any other places where I can check the logs. Can I debug this somehow from some springboot classes.

Form Data

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>

    <title>Demo</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />


</head>
<body>


<!-- Add page specific code/html START -->

<div class="container">
    <h1 th:text="#{welcome.message}"></h1>

    <form class="form-signin" name="loginForm" th:action="@{/login}" action="/login" method="POST">
        <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Please sign in</h2>
        <label for="username" class="sr-only">Email address</label>
        <input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" required="required" autofocus="autofocus" />
        <label for="password" class="sr-only">Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required="required" />

        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign in</button>
    </form>

</div> <!-- /container -->


</body>
</html>
```

HTML code hosted on photon server

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Assessment App</title>

    <link href="../css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="../css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<body>

    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="panel panel-default main-header">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class ="pull-left">Assessments</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="login-container col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-12 col-xs-offset-0">
                <div class="panel panel-login">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <div class="panel-title">Sign In</div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <form id="loginform" class="form-horizontal" role="form">

                            <div class="input-group assessment-input-group">
                                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
                                <input id="login-username" type="text" class="form-control" name="username" value="" placeholder="Username">
                            </div>

                            <div class="input-group assessment-input-group">
                                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></i></span>
                                <input id="login-password" type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password">
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-sm-12 controls">
                                    <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Login">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                        <div class="login-form-error-text hidden">Invalid credentials</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="../javascript/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src ="../javascript/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../javascript/lodash.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../javascript/login.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Corresponding js

```
$(document).ready(function () {


    $('#loginform').submit(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();       
        $.ajax({
            url : 'http://localhost:8080/j_spring_security_check',
            type : 'POST',
            contentType : 'application/json',
            data : JSON.stringify({ j_username :  $('#login-username').val(), j_password : $('#login-password').val() }),
            success : function () {
                window.location.href = '../html/assessment.html';
            },  
            error : function () {
                event.preventDefault();
                alert('failed');
            }
        });
    });

    $('.form-tab-header').on('click', function () {
        $('.login-form-error-text').addClass('hidden');
        $('.form-tab-header').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        $('.form-horizontal').addClass('hidden');
        $('.' + $(this).attr('id') + '-content').removeClass('hidden');
    });
});
```

Security Config

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Value("${ldap.urls}")
    private String ldapUrls;

    @Value("${ldap.base.dn}")
    private String ldapBaseDn;

    @Value("${ldap.user.dn.pattern}")
    private String ldapUserDnPattern;

    @Value("${ldap.enabled}")
    private String ldapEnabled;


    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/login**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/assessments/**").fullyAuthenticated()
                .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                //.loginPage("http://htmlcode.s3-website.us-east-2.amazonaws.com")
                .loginPage("http://localhost:8000")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/j_spring_security_check")
                .usernameParameter("j_username")
                .passwordParameter("j_password")
                //.loginPage("/login")
                .failureUrl("/login?error")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout()
                .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
                .permitAll();

    }



    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/register");
        // .antMatchers("/assessments/**");
    }


    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

        if(Boolean.parseBoolean(ldapEnabled)) {
            auth.ldapAuthentication()
                    .userDetailsContextMapper(userDetailsContextMapper())
                    .userDnPatterns(ldapUserDnPattern)
                    .contextSource()
                    .url(ldapUrls+ldapBaseDn);
        }
    }

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsContextMapper userDetailsContextMapper() {
        return new LdapUserDetailsMapper() {
            @Override
            public UserDetails mapUserFromContext(DirContextOperations ctx, String username, Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
                UserDetails details = super.mapUserFromContext(ctx, username, authorities);
                return details;
            }
        };
    }

    @Bean
    CorsFilter corsFilter() {
        CorsFilter filter = new CorsFilter();
        return filter;
    }
}
```

Comment: I debugged a little bit and it seems that the request doesn't seem to contain the username and password. Not sure why but I have even tried from postman. I got to know this from the UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter class

Comment: I was finally able to get the postman request though when I send data of type x-www-form-urlencoded. How can I do this in ajax?

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to fix this by removing `JSON.stringfy` in my post body of ajax request and setting the content type to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.